# Is there a PHP feed reader for both RSS and ATOM?

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

I need a PHP library/script that can retreive data from feeds, no matter if they are RSS or ATOM, because I want users to insert random feeds which will then be stored in a database. It would also be great if it could check whether a given URL is a feed or not.

If anything exists that could help me out, could anyone tell me? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try these two, they both do RSS and Atom:

- [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)
- [PHP Universal Feed Parser](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2008/05/02/php-universal-feed-parser-lightweight-php-class-for-parsing-rss-and-atom-feeds/)

Comment: Using SimplePie now, works great.

Comment: PHP's greatest rss/api parser -> http://coreylib.com

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html)

> Zend_Feed provides functionality for
>   consuming RSS and Atom feeds. It
>   provides a natural syntax for
>   accessing elements of feeds, feed
>   attributes, and entry attributes.
>   Zend_Feed also has extensive support
>   for modifying feed and entry structure
>   with the same natural syntax, and
>   turning the result back into XML. In
>   the future, this modification support
>   could provide support for the Atom
>   Publishing Protocol.

You don't have to use the entire Zend Framework, just take the Zend_Feed component and its dependencies.

Comment: But you cannot download only the feed component of the ZF. You always have to get the full big fat thing.

Comment: Yeah true. But you can just grab Feed and its dependencies: Exception, Loader, Http, Uri and Validate (http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/requirements.dependencies.html), delete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have created a php feed reader class which can parse both RSS and Atom feed. Here is the link http://raynux.com/blog/2009/09/02/rayfeedreader-php-class-for-parsing-rss-and-atom-feed/.

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily handled by SimpleXML and would require no code from anyone else but yourself.  Just remember that SimpleXML will crap itself if you supply it a file that is invalid or doesn't exist.  Use try/catch + execeptions.

https://www.php.net/simplexml

Comment: You do not want to parse feeds on your own. There are too many dialects and modifications out there.