# how to create rss reader with php?

Tags: php, web-applications, rss, pear, xmlreader

i am creating rss reader application with php.it is basicly getting rss url's from user and with php i am creating an rss reader.But i have some problems how to get rss content with php i try to use pear extension but i had some problem with that.it would be good that seeing some sample code or example application source code which not so complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524024/is-there-a-php-feed-reader-for-both-rss-and-atom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this will help you

[Is there a PHP feed reader for both RSS and ATOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524024/is-there-a-php-feed-reader-for-both-rss-and-atom)

Answer (score 0):

Try an RSS parser, which can also cache the feed to save everyone time and money:

http://lastrss.oslab.net/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) for this in the past

Answer (score 0):

I have built on my own using php and jquery plugin
[How to build RSS feed reader app using PHP and Jquery](http://devlup.com/jquery/how-to-build-rss-feed-reader-app-using-php-and-jquery/2616/)